# Firefox is not responding when loading 800+ data sets in Bar Chart with Charts.Js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, charts, chart.js

I am using Asp.net MVC and my data comes as `List<MyClass>`. Data is populated using foreach loop in the View file to load the bar chart. Length of my data is around 800. When bar chart is start rendering browser becomes unresponsive. I am sure that this issue is because of huge data. It renders after 40-50 seconds. 
Is there any way to render bar chart speedy using chart.js?

Comment: have you tried removing the animations from the chart

Comment: Yes I tried but it is not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that it's actually Chart.js / Firefox that is causing the problem (try it out on other browsers, put a stopwatch right before you call `new Chart...` and stop it in `onAnimationComplete`)

---

While the following steps suggestion should logically reduce the number of calculations, I couldn't see much difference (the chart rendering completes in 0.5 seconds on both IE and Firefox with animation turned off and 7-8 seconds with animation turned on for 800 datasets with 10 points each)

If you are aware of your data range (or if you can calculate this efficiently on the server side), you could override the scale and set your own scale

```
...
scaleOverride: true,
scaleSteps: 10,          // or whatever suits your dataset better
scaleStepWidth: 1,       // or whatever suits your dataset better
scaleStartValue: 0,      // or whatever suits your dataset better
...
```

It might also be a good idea to turn off tooltips if you haven't done so (with 800 data sets, any tooltip you have is not going to be that useful)

```
...
showTooltips: false,
...
```

Comment: Hi @potatopeelings. Thank you very much for your help. Yes you're right. This helped a lot.